# Javascript compute percentages totals on array of objects by key

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Let's say I have the following data structure in Javascript:

```
 const data = [
       {year: 2017, kind: "mammal", animal: "dog", total: 5},
       {year: 2017, kind: "mammal", animal: "dog", total: 3},
       {year: 2016, kind: "mammal", animal: "dog", total: 5},
       {year: 2016, kind: "bird", animal: "chicken", total: 5},
       {year: 2016, kind: "bird", animal: "chicken", total: 90}
 ];
```

I would like to be able to specify a key or multiple keys such as `year` to group the data by. So if I just specified `year` as the group by I would want to compute totals as follows:

```
 [{year: 2017, kind: "mammal", animal: "dog", count: 8, pct: 1},
  {year: 2016, kind: "mammal", animal: "dog", count: 5, pct: 0.05},
  {year: 2016, kind: "bird", animal: "chicken", count: 95, pct: 0.95}]
```

Or if I specified group totals by `year` and `kind` I would want the following:

```
 [{year: 2017, kind: "mammal", animal: "dog", count: 8, pct: 1},
  {year: 2016, kind: "mammal", animal: "dog", count: 5, pct: 1},
  {year: 2016, kind: "bird", animal: "chicken", count: 95, pct: 1}]
```

How could I implement this in Javascript? I have looked at using d3's nest function but haven't successfully wrapped my head around the implementation so far.

Comment: Look at the `sort` and `reduce` methods. [Array Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 1):

I think before you try to implement it, you need to figure out your requirement clearly. From your description, my understanding is that for the result, year+kind+animal is a key for the result items. And your specified group is only used to compute the percentage.

Firstly group the items based on year + kind + animal

```
function groupItems(data){
   var resultMap = {};
   for(var index in data){
      var item = data[index];
      var key = item['year']+'###'+item['kind']+'###'+item['animal'];
      if(!resultMap[key]){
         //copy the item to a new object to make sure it does not update the origin data
         resultMap[key] = Object.assign({}, item); 
      }else{
         // sum them up
         resultMap[key]['total'] = resultMap[key]['total'] +item['total'];
      }
   }
   return Object.values(resultMap);
}
```

Now we have the items, what you need is to compute the percentage based on specified group.

```
function computePercentage(groupedItems, withGroups){
    //compute the total items per specified group
    var totalItemsPerGroup = {};
    for(var index in groupedItems){
        var item = groupedItems[index];
        var keyValues = getValuesFromObjectWithKeys(item, withGroups);
        var strKey = keyValues.join('###');
        if(totalItemsPerGroup[strKey] != undefined){
            totalItemsPerGroup[strKey] += item['total'];
        }else{
            totalItemsPerGroup[strKey] = item['total'];
        }
    }
    // compute percentage based on the total items per specified group calculated
    var result = [];
    for(var index in groupedItems){
        var item = groupedItems[index];
        var keyValues = getValuesFromObjectWithKeys(item, withGroups);
        var strKey = keyValues.join('###');
        var totalCount = totalItemsPerGroup[strKey];
        var percentage = totalCount == 0 ? 0 : item['total'] / totalCount;
        var resultItem = {};
        resultItem['year'] = item['year'];
        resultItem['kind'] = item['kind'];
        resultItem['animal'] = item['animal'];
        resultItem['count'] = item['total'];
        resultItem['pct'] = percentage;
        result.push(resultItem);
    }  
    return result;
}

// a helper function to get values based on specified keys
function getValuesFromObjectWithKeys(obj, keys){
   var result = [];
   for(var i in keys){
       if(obj[keys[i]]){
           result.push(obj[keys[i]]);
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

So to use those functions:

```
var grouppedItems = groupItems(data);
var yearPercentage = computePercentage(grouppedItems , ['year']);
console.log(JSON.stringify(yearPercentage));
var yearKindPercentage = computePercentage(grouppedItems , ['year', 'kind']);
console.log(JSON.stringify(yearKindPercentage ));
var kindAnimalPercentage = computePercentage(grouppedItems , ['kind', 'animal']);
console.log(JSON.stringify(kindAnimalPercentage ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are cleaner ways to do this, especially if you're using `lodash-fp` or `ramda`, but this works (at least for the first result set):

```
const computeBy = (primaryKey, secondary, data) => {

  const groupBy = (key, data) => data.reduce((acc, record) => {
    const value = record[key];
    acc[value] = acc[value] || [];
    acc[value].push(record);
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const groupedByPrimary = groupBy(primaryKey, data);

  const sum = records => records.reduce((acc, v) => acc + v.total, 0);

  return Object.keys(groupedByPrimary).reduce((acc, key) => {
    const group = groupedByPrimary[key];
    const groupTotalCount = sum(group);
    const groupedBySecondary = groupBy(secondary, group);
    const final = Object.values(groupedBySecondary).map(secondaryGroup => {
      const count = sum(secondaryGroup);
      const pct = count / groupTotalCount;
      const recordWithPercentage = Object.assign({}, secondaryGroup[0], { pct, count });
      delete recordWithPercentage.total;
      return recordWithPercentage;
    });
    return acc.concat(final);
  }, []);
}

const result = computeBy('year', 'kind', data).sort((a, b) => a.year < b.year);
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/frb6bowj/2/